# Material Date Range Picker showing incorrect current date Android

Tags: android, datepicker, material-design

The current date in the Material Date Range picker is showing as yesterday's date. I looked into source code for the Material Design Picker and it seems to change the date while getting the date for the UTC timezone.  The current date is the one which is encircled in the calendar. Is there any way to resolve the issue? The date range picker should show the correct date despite of the timezones.

One solution for the problem would be to change the current date manually, and I tried looking in the source code for the Datepicker but dont seem to find a method for this. Can the current date of Material Date Range picker be changed?

I am initialising the date picker as:

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
final MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker = builder.build();
materialDatePicker.show(fragmentManager, materialDatePicker.toString());
```

Kindly help.

Comment: There is a bug. Check https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1360 and https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/882

Comment: They haven't fixed it yet, and have closed the issue! Have asked for the release of the update, thanks for the timely reply!

Comment: Hi, the issue is resolved now, thanks

Comment: No, this still exists!

Comment: @Patriotic kindly refer to this comment - https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1360#issuecomment-644790081

Comment: issue still not resolved i check material:1.3.0

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed in the last release:

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.2.0-rc01

*Fixed issue that caused highlighting the wrong day as today* ->
[commit](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/d9b98743e5b6ab13f1e256619da5fcf2e0d8f50a)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the library to: material:1.3.0-alpha02 and it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Tried 1.4.0. It is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I'm also faced with the same issue. I have made some searches but looks like there is an issue in the `material` library.
I have fond some code and fixed the issue:

```
        CalendarConstraints.Builder calendarConstraintBuilder = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
        calendarConstraintBuilder.setValidator(DateValidatorPointBackward.now());

        dateBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
        dateBuilder.setTitleText("Select Date Range");
        dateBuilder.setCalendarConstraints(calendarConstraintBuilder.build());
        MaterialDatePicker<Pair<Long, Long>> picker = dateBuilder.build();
        picker.setMenuVisibility(false);
        picker.setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(false);
        picker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), picker.toString());

        picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(selection -> {

            Calendar utc = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            utc.setTimeInMillis(selection.first);
            String startDate = calendarToDate(getActivity(), utc, "dd-MMM-yyyy");
            utc.setTimeInMillis(selection.second);
            String endDate = calendarToDate(getActivity(), utc, "dd-MMM-yyyy");

            date.setText(startDate+" to "+endDate);

        });
```

And here is `calendarToDate` method:

```
public String calendarToDate(Context context, Calendar calendar, String dateFormat) {
    if (calendar == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Locale locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, locale);
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    df.setTimeZone(timeZone);

    Date d = calendar.getTime();
    return df.format(d);
}
```